pyhtml2pdf and pdfkit not working as expected
I need to convert a URL to pdf. Most links are working fine, but there are some which are slow in loading or in this case doing a connection security check, which results in pdf page with a bad result (compare expected vs outcome).
To counter this I used timeout as converter.convert(url, pdf_filename, **timeout=10**), but this resulted in error
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59394/devtools/browser/45008637-d758-43a7-b715-a03731ae80e9
[0521/102951.525:INFO:CONSOLE(1910)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.insightsonindia.com/2024/05/20/mission-2024-insights-daily-current-affairs-pib-summary-20-May-2024/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://www.insightsonindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Cheltenham-Light.ttf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.", source: https://www.insightsonindia.com/2024/05/20/mission-2024-insights-daily-current-affairs-pib-summary-20-May-2024/ (1910)

... some similar lines, can't post whole as SO flagging this as spam...

[0521/102952.513:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.4.1", source: https://www.insightsonindia.com/wp-content/cache/min/1/c/6.5.3/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1716204483 (2)
[0521/102953.508:INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/125.0.6422.61 Safari/537.36", source: https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-2787889.js?sv=7 (3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\change move user pc\python website data download\finallinkstopdf.py", line 31, in <module>
    converter.convert(url, pdf_filename, timeout=10)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyhtml2pdf\converter.py", line 45, in convert
    file.write(result)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

Further to counter this error I tried
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--window-size=1980,1020")
options.add_argument("--headles=news")
options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.6422.61 Safari/537.36")


and used wkhtml2pdf, pdfkit with delay, but that is also producing the same outcome. These both are really slow on some sites in general, so I'm not using them anymore.
I also tried changing the link from https to http, and changing site settings to allow insecure, neither of them worked.
Also if I put time to zero as converter.convert(url, pdf_filename, **timeout=0**), it's not giving an error, but getting same unexpected outcome.
Is there any solution for it, or any other python library that can make this work.

Does this answer your question? how to save opened page as pdf in Selenium (Python)
